# Place to upload large image accompanying the question

Tags: discussion

Assume my photography question must be accompanied by the image. The image is full-resolution, 6-7MB size. What is suggested place to upload it ?

Answer (score 7):

If you need to do that, assuming JPEG, then Flickr is probably the route to go. It's not all that uncommon here to use the image upload for this site to show the basic image in a smaller size and then use a link to Flickr for a larger.

Comment: Doesn't Flickr strip out the EXIF, though?

Comment: No, that's controlled by the user, some leave it (I do) and others remove it. You can see the EXIF info for an image by clicking on the camera model in the upper right. You'll see text to the effect of "This photo was taken on April 26, 2011 using a Pentax K-5." And the Pentax K-5 will be a link to the EXIF.

Comment: But it does get taken out of the actual jpeg, right? Or did they stop that?

Comment: @mattdm - Dunno, I haven't checked. However, if the user here links to Flickr for their image in an anchor tag, rather than img tag, then no problem which was what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Er.. please don't!

Use a small version (our post width here is about 630px so anything bigger than that is a waste) and provide a link to the larger version elsewhere if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[DropBox](http://db.tt/HPbAQVf) works well for those cases where you want to give a link to a full sized image without it being manipulated by any photo sharing site.